# How to tighten a Fox Thru Axle, Cam Lever/QR Skewer?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, hub, axle

The cam lever on my Fox Thru Axle is loose but its unlike the Rockshox axle where you can just tighten it up with a little allen key at the top.

(edit from comment below) *The quick release lever is a bit wobbly on the axle, It feels like it needs to be tightened more to the axle just like how you would tighten the Rockshox Maxle with a little allen key at the top of the head but I don't know how to do it with the Fox/Shimano one.*

How do I tighten it up to the axle itself? Do I push and turn or what?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Fox QR15 thru axle (sounds like it), the only thing that's supposed to be adjustable is the rotational position of the axle nut in its splines, which if needed is done by loosening the 2.5mm bolt that keeps the axle nut keeper in place and sliding the keeper out of the way. To fasten down the axle, you thread it in much like threading a normal QR skewer in the QR nut, stopping when the lever begins to require force when it's about halfway through its travel, or parallel with the axle. You adjust the axle nut's position to make sure the lever ends up positioned how you want it when fastened and all the way down, i.e. tucked neatly in front of the fork leg.

Comment: Hey, I was talking about the quick release lever being a bit wobbly on the axle, It feels like it needs to be tightened more to the axle just like how you would tighten the Rockshox Maxle with a little allen key at the top of the head but I don't know how to do it with the Fox/Shimano one. thanks

Comment: I see. The lever is supposed to be permanently fixed to the axle and I haven't ever had to mess with this aspect of one. I looked at the inside of one with a light today and if I had to guess, what they do is thread the lever part in and glue or loctite the threads in place.

Comment: Okay thanks, but how do you take it off to put loctite on the threads, is the question?

Comment: How much is sticking out exactly, and what happens when you try to tighten down the axle? I'm only hypothesizing here, but if it is put together with just some high strength loctite, and that's come loose, you may be able to get it the rest of the way by clamping the axle in a vice in some way that won't hurt it (like maybe wood blocks with an appropriate hole drilled out) and turning the "skewer" out.

Comment: Its not sticking out much, maybe a few mm or a CM but it wobbles and I don't want the quick release to fall or snap off, so to tighten it I put the axle part in a vice then turn quick release lever part and that will take it off or tighten it? then put loctite on threads?

Comment: Again I'm just guessing about what to do to correct it. If you shine a light inside the axle can you see the hole the lever part is installed into, and see any gap there that indicates it may have come out? When I looked at one the other day, the end of the "skewer" was flush with the top of the hole.